# Web dav (non-sharepoint) opening MS-office without login prompt

Tags: authentication, ms-office, webdav

Does anyone know how to open MS-office files without login prompt for Web DAV? I've tried editing the registry, saving the password in credential manager, etc.. 
however it still prompts me whenever I open up my Excel or Word file.

Comment: Transform title casing, removed some unnecessary niceties and improved the grammar a little.

Answer (score 0):

Note that when using windows explorer, or internet explorer, to browse files and launch for editing, this is a seperate process and executable from MS Office. The authentication state is not shared between processes, nor are cookies.

Any webdav client will display a login prompt when the web server replies to a request with a 401, which is normally after an anonymous request to a secure resource. Webdav clients will usually not send credentials pre-emptively, they send them in response to a challenge.

So to prevent the login prompt in http://milton.io we provide a framework to embed authentication tokens in the URL. This solves the problem for launching from web browsers (IE) but is not generally helpful for browsing with windows explorer.

If you are launching from windows explorer a better solution is to use a true drive mapping tool such as NetDrive.